# checkbox onclick/onselect

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
$('#Container').append('<input type="checkbox" id = '+ data[i].name + '/> ' + data[i].name + '<br />');
```

I have the above code to create checkboxes dynamically. Based on selecting/deselecting the checkbox I want to manipulate a few things.

1. If I select 2 checkboxes, I want to store that as an array and store it to hidden field. Is it possible to store array into hidden field?

```
var selected = new Array();
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Want to store selected in hidden field so that i can pass it to another method.

1. I want to capture the ids of selected checkboxes in another method (ie. in the on change of selection) For drop down

   `$('#dropdownid').change()` will be used
   similarly i want to use for checkbox selection.

select checkbox
store the values of the checkboxes in an array.
Send that array into someother method along with the ids.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store things in another field to pass them to a *function* (is that what you mean with the word 'method'?) - javascript functions can access variables and variables or parameters would be the natural way to share information with methods.

On the other hand if you want to make the data available to the server-side, via a form POST, then you would want it in a hidden field, and you're probably best of encoding it as JSON as fields can only include text. You'd need to decode the JSON server-side.